# Using in_category for non standard loops

Tags: loop, conditional-tags

Im using [wp favorite posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-favorite-posts/) to show a list of favorited post by a user on a page. It creates a loop of posts but I can't figure out how to use conditional tags for posts in the loop. Specifically for posts in a certain category I need to show the image inside the loop below. So in the regular loop on my index page I just use `in_category'. But that isn't working with how the favorites loop is setup. Any suggestions on how to do this? Here's the loop.

```
<?php
echo "<div id='boxes'>";
if (!empty($user)):
    if (!wpfp_is_user_favlist_public($user)):
        echo "$user's Favorite Posts.";
    else:
        echo "$user's list is not public.";
    endif;
endif;

if ($wpfp_before):
    echo "<p>".$wpfp_before."</p>";
endif;

if ($favorite_post_ids):
    $favorite_post_ids = array_reverse($favorite_post_ids);
    foreach ($favorite_post_ids as $post_id) {
        $p = get_post($post_id);
        $video_code = get_post_meta($post_id,'video_code',true);
        ?>
       <div class="box">   
        <div class="rel">
         <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post_id); ?>" rel="<?php echo $post_id; ?>" class="postpopup">
          //HERE I NEED TO USE IN_CATEGORY TO ONLY SHOW THIS IMAGE WHEN THE  POST IS IN CATEGORY "8".//
          <img src="<?php $thumb = get_youtube_screen_link( $video_code, 'default' ); ?>" width="176" height="126"></img>
          <?php echo get_the_title($post_id); ?>
          <?php wpfp_remove_favorite_link($post_id); ?> 
        </div>
       </div>
   <?php }
else:
    echo "<li>";
    echo $wpfp_options['favorites_empty'];
    echo "</li>";
endif;
wpfp_clear_list_link();
echo "</div>";
wpfp_cookie_warning();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Just need to add $post_id to the template tag like so.

```
if (in_category('videos',$post_id)) {
```